# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.'

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem with implementing this line with SQL.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{
      query +=  @"WHERE FirstName LIKE @Search OR LastName LIKE @Search OR Phone LIKE @Search OR Address LIKE @Search";
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Search", $"%{search}%"));
}
```

I don´t know what to do...

Comment: Have you tried printing out your final `query` to see what's actually being sent to the SQL server?

Comment: I already knew what the mistake was. I needed to separate the word WHERE from the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{
      query +=  @" WHERE FirstName LIKE @Search OR LastName LIKE @Search OR Phone LIKE @Search OR Address LIKE @Search";
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Search", $"%{search}%"));
}

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE part of your query looks valid at first sight.
Try adding a space before WHERE. If text from a FROM clause or a table join is right next to WHERE with no white-space the SQL parser doesn't necessarily understand that the WHERE part begins there, but can think it's a part of the preceding part.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help!